# AMP Web Stories | Publisher logo is not updating in Google Search Results and Discover

Tags: amp-html, google-search, google-search-console, amp-stories

My AMP web story shows up in Google Search Results and in Discover.  I've updated the logo a couple months back. The publisher logo in the top left is showing an older image in the search results but the actual web story shows the correct updated image.

1. In Search Console I've done URL inspection and everything passes
2. I've refeshed the amp cache manually with https://amp-travel.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/
3. I've recrawled my site-map just in case

Is there anything else I can try without impacting how that specific story ranks?  Does removing outdated content tool in Search Console impact rank?

Answer (score 0):

Google Search Results take time to display updated content from websites. It might take from 2 days to even a month to display new images, graphics depending on the number of changes you have done in the content.

What you can do is:

1. Submit the updated URL again in the Google Search console. This way Google crawlers will crawl it again and maybe update the search results further.
2. Similarly submit the updated sitemap for the same.

I have tried it multiple times for content updates and got better search results.

Refer to this Google support answer for more information:

1. https://support.google.com/news/publisher-center/thread/54060133?hl=en